# Qt - Run function in Separate Thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have a function that is triggered by a button click. When executed, it iterates the files within a given directory, reading each one and then sending the contents to a client over a socket connection. For each file that is sent, the contents are written back to the gui. There is also a button that is to be used to stop the iteration. As of now, I am handling this in the main thread however, as expected, the gui becomes somewhat unresponsive. I have attempted to execute the function in another thread however, my implementation is worse than running in the main thread! See below, everything resides in the same class. What is the best method for handling this?

```
private:    
QThread mSendDirectoryFilesThread;

private slots:
void onSendDirectoryFilesClicked();
void onStopSendingDirectoryFilesClicked();
void sendDirectoryFiles();
```

**wire up slot etc. on class instantiation**

```
moveToThread(&mSendDirectoryFilesThread);
connect(&mSendDirectoryFilesThread, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(sendDirectoryFiles()));
```

**send button click signal**

```
void MainView::onSendDirectoryFilesClicked()
{
    mSendDirectoryFilesThread.start();
}
```

**send function**

```
void MainView::sendDirectoryFiles() {
    QDir packetDir(ui->txtSelectedDirectory->text());
        packetDir.setNameFilters(QStringList() << "*.xml");
    QStringList dirFiles = packetDir.entryList();

    if (dirFiles.count() > 0) {
        ui->btnStopSendingDirectoryFiles->setEnabled(true);

        foreach (QString f, dirFiles) {
            QApplication::processEvents();

            QFile file(ui->txtSelectedDirectory->text() + QDir::separator() + f);
            mDocToSend = getFileXML(file);

            if (mDocToSend.isDocument()) {
                if (mSocket.sendDoc(mDocToSend)) {
                    addToPacketLog(mDocToSend.toString(), "SENT");
                    QThread::sleep(ui->txtTransmitInterval->text().toInt());
                } else {
                    qDebug() << "Nothing to send";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**stop button click signal**

```
void MainView::onStopSendingDirectoryFilesClicked()
{
    mSendDirectoryFilesThread.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: how about just using QtConcurrent::run to execute sendDirectoryFiles()  in a separate thread ?

Answer (score 0):

`MainView::sendDirectoryFiles` is not executed in the worker thread, because [`connect`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect) uses [`Qt::AutoConnection`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) by default, which means that the function is called in the thread of the slot object, i.e. `this` in your example. You can change the default behavior by explicitly choosing a `Qt::DirectConnection`:

```
connect(&mSendDirectoryFilesThread, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(sendDirectoryFiles()), Qt::DirectConnection);
```

**Further considerations**

- Note that `MainView::sendDirectoryFiles` should be thread safe, which is not the case. For example, you are changing the GUI by calling `ui->btnStopSendingDirectoryFiles->setEnabled(true);`, which is not allowed.
- You may also want to call `mSendDirectoryFilesThread.exit(0)` at the end of `MainView::sendDirectoryFiles`, otherwise you will not be able to perform the operation twice without stopping the operation first explicitly.
- Using `QtConcurrent::run` as pointed out by H. Gomaa, may be a clearer solution, but the called method should still be thread safe.
- You may consider adding a new signal to a derived class of `QThread`, which invokes the operation instead of starting/stopping the thread. Using a [`QThreadPool`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthreadpool.html) and a `QRunnable` task may be a good idea too.